# Transfer files from s3 bucket to amazon RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am trying to load data from the s3 bucket to amazon RDS database. I know this is not the programming question. But I really appreciate help. I have used the code below:

```
aws rds restore-db-instance-from-s3 ^
--allocated-storage 250 ^ 
--db-instance-identifier myidentifier ^
--db-instance-class db.m4.large ^
--engine mysql ^
--master-user-name masterawsuser ^
--master-user-password masteruserpassword ^
--s3-bucket-name mybucket ^
--s3-ingestion-role-arn arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/rolename ^
--s3-prefix bucketprefix ^
--source-engine mysql ^
--source-engine-version 5.6.27
```

But I am getting the below error, though I have given correct ARN number:

```
“An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the   RestoreDBInstanceFrom S3 operation: IAM role ARN value is invalid or does not include the   required permissions for: S3_SNAPSHOT_INGESTION”
```

Any comments on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying the role you have specified actually has the required permissions for `S3_SNAPSHOT_INGESTION`?

Comment: @MarkB, yes!! It has all the permissions for `S3_SNAPSHOT_INGESTION`.

Comment: While the official page for `restore-db-instance-from-s3` doesn't provide a lot of information [Import RDS from S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-s3.html "RDS import from S3"), you can follow [Importing Data into an Amazon RDS MySQL DB Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html#MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Enabling.IAM) that lists specific IAM policies for importing from S3.

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to the game, but this is the #1 hit on Google and I spent about an hour figuring this problem out.

That error message is a bit misleading. It has nothing to do with the role or policies that you have attached to RDS. In my case, the account I was logged in as did not use a role with the proper permissions. In AWS `IAM`, I added the policies `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonRDSFullAccess` to my user account (well, actually added them to my assumed role because I'm using a Federated Corporate Access).

Once I did that, the error message disappeared and I was able to restore from S3

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot and saved some time.

Comment: In my case, it was an issue with the role that I gave to RDS. That role did not have the proper Trust Relationship. I needed to make sure "rds.amazonaws.com" was in the JSON

`{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{"Effect": "Allow","Principal": {"Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"},"Action": "sts:AssumeRole"}]}`

Comment: I had a trust relationship to EC2 but not to RDS, so I had to set up an array in there instead: `{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow","Principal": {"Service": ["ec2.amazonaws.com","rds.amazonaws.com"]},"Action": "sts:AssumeRole"}]}`