# What permissions do i need to set for boto3 rds.restore_db_instance_from_s3()?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to restore a rds on my AWS cloud from a .bak file on my S3 bucket.

I keep runing into the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RestoreDBInstanceFromS3 operation: IAM role ARN value is invalid or does not include the required permissions for: S3_SNAPSHOT_INGESTION
```

I guess the error lies within my value of the field:

```
S3IngestionRoleArn='string'
```

I can't find any ressources what exact permissions are needed or what exactely this field wants to have.

There is no information concerning the error with: "S3_SNAPSHOT_INGESTION"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just run into the same issue, I had to create a new Role with `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonRDSFullAccess` and use that.

[I did find a similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54226610/7644446) that helped me to find the solution.