# creating rds db from aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-rds

I trying to create aws rds db from s3 bucket which has data backup, but getting errors this "We're sorry, your request to create DB instance database-1 has failed.
IAM role ARN value is invalid or does not include the required permissions for: S3_SNAPSHOT_INGESTION", I also gave full permission.

I tried to create rds db from s3 bucket ei backup stored, but getting this problems "We're sorry, your request to create DB instance database-1 has failed.
IAM role ARN value is invalid or does not include the required permissions for: S3_SNAPSHOT_INGESTION"

Comment: I added the following trust policies and permissions from this post and I got a little further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702032/transfer-files-from-s3-bucket-to-amazon-rds-database/54226610#54226610